# I can not listen User document from Firestore using ProxyProvider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I use Provider widget for State Management. I wrapped MaterialApp with MultiProvider, which contains StreamProvider and ProxyProvider which take FirebaseUser.uid and return Stream of User Document in Firestore. In UserScreen I wrapped Scaffold with StreamProvider with value of Provider<ProxyProvider(above). Also I used Consumer to take user document and I use this scheme in every scene which I need realtime response from User Document. Everything works fine but when I go to another page with PushRemoveUntil and go back StreamProvider does not work and I see loading Widget infinitely.

```
 providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged),
        ProxyProvider<FirebaseUser,Stream<UserClass>>(update: (BuildContext context, FirebaseUser user, _,) => UserStream(user?.uid).locationInfo(),),
      ],



class UserScreen extends StatelessWidget {
static var id = 'UserScreen';
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final usersData = Provider.of<Stream<UserClass>>(context);
var c = Theme.of(context);
var provide = Provider.of<ProviderData>(context);
var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return StreamProvider<UserClass>.value(
  value: usersData,
  initialData: UserClass.initialData(),
  child:Consumer<UserClass>(
      builder: (context, users, child){
      return MyScaffold();
    }
   ),
  );
 }
}`
```